# GitAttribute to force manual merging specific file

Tags: git

My repository has a *version.json* where we store the major and minor version of the code base.

**How can I configure git to not automatically merge changes to that file?**

For example, the *version.json* file has `{ "version": "1.2"}` and I have two feature branches that bump it to "1.3", I want the last merge to conflict:

```
A--B-----PR1--PR2
   | \  /     /
   |  F1     /
   F2--------
```

Both `F1` and `F2` make the same change to the *version.json* file, they both edit it to be `{ "version: "1.3" }`.  The merge commit `PR1` is fine, but I'd like the merge `PR2` to require a manual review of the *version.json* file (because we'll need to set the version to 1.4).

I tried creating a *.gitattribute* to treat the *version.json* file as binary, but git seemed to still be able to merge the results.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to be able to find a solution to do what you want.  You can use the `merge` attribute to control how files that differ are merged, but in your case you have two identical files.

When Git does a merge of two different commits, it compares each file in the tree in both heads that it's merging (in this case, PR1 and F2), taking into account renames.  If the files are identical in both cases (that is, the blobs have the same hash), then it will merge them by just taking the version that's in both heads as the result without considering anything else.

This is the case you have: both sides have the same file in an identical state, so Git doesn't consider that any merge needs to be done, and consequently doesn't invoke any merge code or honor any attributes related to merges.  It doesn't matter that your trees are otherwise different: the differing files will be merged, but the identical files won't have the merge machinery invoked.

If you had two files that differed, you could use `version.json -merge` to cause them to conflict any time they changed, but that will have no effect on identical files.

If the semantic you're going for is to bump the version on each commit or merge, then it's better to compute the version by using Git and some sort of script rather than changing the file in the repository each time.

Comment: bk2204 - I'm not sure I follow you when you discuss files plural.  In my case I only have a single file that has been edited in two feature branches, but the edits are identical.  The commit ids will be different though.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover this better, but if both sides have the same blob ID (that is, the files are identical), Git takes that as the merged state for that file and doesn't let you customize the merge.  Whether the trees or commits differ otherwise doesn't matter.

Comment: It's even a bit worse than that, because if the merge base is the same as one "side" of the merge but different from the other, Git will just take whichever side is *different*, again without invoking your merge driver. (Though in this particular use-case, that may be OK.)